# why does the list size return 0?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

why the list size return 0 in toast?

**Activity Class**

```
List<Models> models= new ArrayList<>();
List<String> Images = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        putData();
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + models.get(0).Images.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    void putData() {


        for (int x = 1; x <= 6; x++) {
            Images.add(String.valueOf(x) + ".png");
        }
        models.add(new Model(Images));
        Images.clear();



    }
```

**Model Class**

```
public class Models {


    List<String> Images;

    public Models(List<String> images) {
        Images = images;
    }
}
```

I hope you help me...........................................................

Comment: Because you clear the list afterwards?

Comment: I know that but it is supposed to be stored in the array before deleting it

Comment: As per [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), variable names should start with a lowercase first letter. Instead of  `List<String> Images` we write `List<String> images`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of this line:

```
Images.clear();
```

which clears the list `Images`. 
Maybe you think that `Images` and `models.get(0).Images` are 2 different lists. 
They are not as they both point to the same list. 
Remove this

```
List<String> Images = new ArrayList<>();
```

from your activity class declarations and change `putData()`:

```
void putData() {
    List<String> Images = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int x = 1; x <= 6; x++) {
        Images.add(String.valueOf(x) + ".png");
    }
    models.add(new Model(Images));
}
```

Comment: It might seem, that Images and models.get(0).Images are different lists but both of them are referencing to the same memory locations. So, once you clear datafor Images will remove the data from models.get(0).Images as well.

Comment: @SnehaSarkar I delete pictures from the list because I want to fill in other pictures for other data

Comment: @haley Then you need to create one object of Images inside the putData method as a local variable. No need to clear the data again.

Comment: can you put example please

Comment: but I have like codes inside putData 10 times then I wanna list for every loop

Comment: @haley If you declare `Images` inside `putData()` you don't need `Images.clear()`. This is the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've called clear() on the images. They are gone by the point you call size().

Comment: I know that but it is supposed to be stored in the array before deleting it

Comment: No. It's not copied in. It's assigned by reference. When you clear the items out from the images List it is referring to, they are gone as far as anything else that was referring to it is concerned too.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're retaining the instance of `Images` and then calling `clear()` on it.

When you create a new ArrayList in Java, something like:

```
ArrayList<Something> somethings = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then pass it to another class:

```
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(somethings);
```

the ArrayList contained by SomeClass is the *exact same* one referenced by `somethings`.

When you call `putData()`, you're passing a single instance of your ArrayList to your Models class.

You do fill it, but then you immediately clear it. Since you clear the `Images` list in your `putData()` class, you also clear the `Images` list in your Models instance, because the two lists are the same.

Make it a local variable and remove the `clear()`:

```
void putData() {
    ArrayList<String> Images = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int x = 1; x <= 6; x++) {
        Images.add(String.valueOf(x) + ".png");
    }
    models.add(new Model(Images));
}
```

Comment: I want to put each group of different data from the images for this reason I delete it

Comment: That's why you need to use a local variable. Each time you call `putData()`, it will have a unique list of images.

Comment: you could, in a loop, create a new Images object, and add that to models and would be fine.

Don't try to clean it up though. the stuff in the previous list is still being used once you add it to another list. It's holding a pointer/reference to the data. If you clear() it, it's gone. 

You could put a for loop around everything you've done without the call to clear() at all and it would work fine.